# Corrupted output video from ffmpeg combining few videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation, ffprobe

Ran ffmpeg on Windows 10 to concatanate 4 videos in this sequence:
            `introduction.mp4 1.mp4 2.mp4 3.mp4`
        to create combined.mp4

`1.mp4 2.mp4 and 3.mp4` were created identically by ffmpeg from a longer video

When playing `combined.mp4` the `introduction.mp4` part was OK, but after that the video stopped.
If I jumped forward got green and other color blank screen

This was the ffmpeg command to concatenate:

```
set parm=-probesize 1000 -analyzeduration 100000000 -fpsprobesize 1000
c:/tools/ffmpeg64/bin/ffmpeg %parm% -loglevel warning -y -strict -2 -f concat -i videoList.txt -c copy combined.mp4
```

This was the videoList.txt file:

```
file introduction.mp4
file 1.mp4
file 2.mp4
file 3.mp4
```

The input files attributes are not the same

introduction.mp4    1456x1028 25fps     111knps total  175kbps

1.mp4               1280x720  29.97fpd 1107kbps total 1233kbps

OUTPUT: combined.mp4 1456x1028 4.11 fps 1456kbps total 151kbps

Comment: Share the output of `ffmpeg -i introduction.mp4` and `ffmpeg -i 1.mp4`.

Comment: Don't understand. Can you be more specific?